# How can I prevent programs from running reboot scripts or "reload your computer scripts from start up"?

Tags: bash

I would like to prevent any program within my PC from running modified scripts without 
super user authorization, such as instruction on rebooting my pc from start up to forcing 
through software updates.

How can I prevent packages from calling **strong text**/usr/share/update-notifier/notify-reboot-required this is to prevent any malicious program from running within my pc?

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actions you mentioned, rebooting and installing, can only be done by root. So, if you deny those programs root access you'll be fine.  And anyway, you shouldn't allow random programs to run as root.

This is the default behavior. Remember,  don't type "sudo"  before a command unless your command actually needs root access and you've verified that it won't work without root.  Also,  don't type your password into a password prompt unless you're sure about what will happen.

Comment: Thank you very much for these helpful tips, I am really liking this place.